# Watson Dialog parsing input node

Tags: ibm-watson

In a Watson dialog xml file, we are trying to query the user for a twitter handle and then assign that twitter handle to the Dialog profile variable Twitter_Handle. The associated input node is triggered by "$ @*"

If the user were to type in say "their twitter handle is @xxxxx" I don't want to assign that whole phrase to Twitter_Handle... just the "@xxxxx" part.

Is there a way within Dialog to parse the users input to look for say the "@" and what immediately follows so that I can assign just the actual twitter handle to Twitter_Handle?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and I was using Java so here what I did. You can check if the user input contains the symbol '@' and then try to split the whole answer in strings and get the string right after the '@'.